# QTextEdit not displaying all information, but qDebug() is

Tags: c++, qt

I am not sure what is going on here, but for some reason my QTextEdit Object is not correctly displaying the information it should.

I am trying to read a QString with the following format/pattern:
`<A>` `</A>` and `<A/>`

My Test QString is:
`<a> <b> </b> <c/> <d> </e> </a> <a/>`

I have a QTextEdit Object called `OUTPUT` that I use to display the end result.

The fragment of Code I use is:

```cpp
    QStringList tags1;

    QRegularExpression re("[<][a-zA-Z0-9]+[/][>]");     //RegEx for <A/> format
    QRegularExpression re1("[<][a-zA-Z0-9_]+[>]");      //RegEx for <A> format
    QRegularExpression re2("[<][/][a-zA-Z0-9_]+[>]");   //RegEx for </A> format

    tags1 = XS.split(" ");          //Splitting the QString by whitespace
//    tags1 = XS.split(QRegularExpression("//s");           //tried this, doesn't do what I want
                                                            //leaves every tag as whitespace

    OUTPUT->append(XS);             //not being displayed in OUTPUT
    qDebug() << XS;                 //is being displayed in Debug

    OUTPUT->append(QString::number(tags1.count()));
    //just a function to show me that 'tags1' has the correct number of elements
    //works properly

    foreach(QString b, tags1)
    {
        QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match(b);
        if(match.hasMatch())
        {
            qDebug() << b;
            OUTPUT->append(b);
        }
    }
    //only the first item is displayed in OUTPUT
    //the second item is displayed as whitespace
    //everything is displayed in Debug

    foreach(QString b, tags1)
    {
        QRegularExpressionMatch match = re1.match(b);
        if(match.hasMatch())
        {
            qDebug() << b;
            OUTPUT->append(b);
        }
    }
    //only the 3rd item is displayed in OUTPUT
    //the rest are just blank whitespaces


    foreach(QString b, tags1)
    {
        QRegularExpressionMatch match = re2.match(b);
        if(match.hasMatch())
        {
            qDebug() << b;
            OUTPUT->append(b);
        }
    }
    //the three items displayed in OUTPUT here are correctly displayed
```

Running the program, `OUTPUT` displays this:
`8`
`<c/>`
 
 
 
`<d>`
`</b>`
`</e>`
`</a>`

whilst the Debug output is displayed correctly.

what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know much Qt, but [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) says that `QTextEdit` can do rich text formatting with HTML, so I guess your input is interpreted as HTML and outputted as such?

Comment: Take a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/richtext-html-subset.html. This will explain a lot

Comment: Try adding text with `QTextEdit::insertPlainText()` instead of `append()`.